# How much rep have I earned today?

Tags: support, reputation

Three different sources are saying three different things.

Hovering over my name shows a value of 249 for today.

Hovering over today's "bar" in the rep graph shows 253.

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation shows 245

Which is the correct value?  245 seems right, since I've had 3 accepts, so that's where I should cap out, and I seem to recal `/reputation` being *a priori* always correct, but I wanted to make sure.  Not worried, just wondering.

Also, if anyone's wondering, these various off by four differences are caused by my own stupidity.  I've deleted **two** answers of score -2.  Between deletes I did a manual recalc to "fix" my rep.  I guess these three sources pull based on different calculations, all treating deletions differently.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `/reputation` is the most correct value. The other stuff will catch up eventually.